# Spark - time difference within each group

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

Given a streaming data, how to calculate the time difference between first and last message in the same group?

Input: message on kafka topic, 1 message per topic

```
MESSAGE |      TIME 
----------------------------
MESSAGE1 | 2019-01-01 14:00:00  # group for MESSAGE1

MESSAGE1 | 2019-01-01 14:05:00

MESSAGE1 | 2019-01-01 14:10:00

MESSAGE2 | 2019-01-01 14:15:00  # group for MESSAGE2

MESSAGE2 | 2019-01-01 14:20:00

MESSAGE1 | 2019-01-01 14:25:00  # new group for MESSAGE1

MESSAGE1 | 2019-01-01 14:30:00
```

Expected Result: when the message was received for the first time, don't do anything. For the second, if the same message was received in sequence, calculate timediff.

In this case, initially time difference for AAA was 5 min when 2nd message is received, which got updated to 10 min after receiving 3rd message

```
MESSAGE  | TIME_DIFF
----------------------
MESSAGE1 |  10 minutes # initially when the first time message1 received, dont do anything. Later for 2nd message, the time difference is calculated to 5min. When message1 received for 3rd time, time difference would be updated from 5min to 10min
MESSAGE2 |   5 minutes
MESSAGE1 |   5 minutes
```

Tried to perform as below, could not figure out the approach.

```
# Read data from Kafka Topic as Dataframe

df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")

# Initialize for 1st msg 

msg_name = df.msg
inital_timestamp = df.time

# subsequent 2nd  msg onwards
# check if current msg is same as earlier message ie. msg_name

temp_list = []

if df['message'] == msg_name:
    var_compute_diff = df[time] - inital_timestamp
    <write to s3, when to write?>
    <Handling cases where we need to persists AAA t times as shown in output above>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by grouping by MESSAGE column and for each new data keep the min and max for the TIME column, then calculate the difference.

Here's a possible scenario using your data:

Initialize the dataframe that will contain the diff column:

```
diff_df = None
```

Then we receive the first time:

```
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
```

Let's suppose the data is

```
["MESSAGE1", "2019-01-01 14:00:00"]
```

Then we will prepare the new data, you will know in a second why:

```
new_data = df.withColumn("MIN_TIME", col("TIME")).withColumn("MAX_TIME", col("TIME")).withColumn("TIME_DIFF", lit(0))\
    .select("MESSAGE", "MIN_TIME", "MAX_TIME", "TIME_DIFF")
```

Then the result will be:

```
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+
|MESSAGE |MIN_TIME           |MAX_TIME           |TIME_DIFF|
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+
|MESSAGE1|2019-01-01 14:00:00|2019-01-01 14:00:00|0        |
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+
```

Then will check if diff_df is none or not for the first time, if not will do a union with the new data:

```
if diff_df is None:
    diff_df = new_data
else:
    diff_df = diff_df.union(new_data)
```

After that, you need to do a groupBy on the diff_df to recalculate the diff column after adding the new data:

```
diff_df = diff_df.groupby("MESSAGE").agg(
        functions.min(col("MIN_TIME")).alias("MIN_TIME"),
        functions.max(col("MAX_TIME")).alias("MAX_TIME")
    ).withColumn("TIME_DIFF", unix_timestamp(col("MAX_TIME")) - unix_timestamp(col("MIN_TIME")))
```

And so on each time there are new data you do the same operation, here's the result of your input from the post (Note the diff column is in seconds, if you want minutes then you have to divide it by 60 + rounding):

```
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+
|MESSAGE |MIN_TIME           |MAX_TIME           |TIME_DIFF|
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+
|MESSAGE1|2019-01-01 14:00:00|2019-01-01 14:30:00|1800     |
|MESSAGE2|2019-01-01 14:15:00|2019-01-01 14:20:00|300      |
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+
```

Comment: this may not work for MESSAGE1. In the above data , the 6th and 7th message is MESSAGE1 (5th message is MESSAGE2). so for 7th message, we need to consider the min time from 6th input stream MESSAGE1, not the 1st row MESSAGE1. ie. time difference within each message group, recalculate if the previous message is different. In this case 5th message is MESSAGE2, so for 6th message MESSAGE1 onwards recompute within the group starting from 6th message (as mentioned in the output).

Comment: @steve In that case the group By query is enough, it is up to you when to call it.